# Is there a way to Turn this Flash Configrator into PHP or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'am thinking about to turn this flash application into php or javascript.

Here is the example:
http://bit.ly/uAjsm6

With php everytime the customer selects a color and the page must reload.
If I do it with ajax, I cant find a solution to give the selected value into php.

Do you know a better solution without flash?

Comment: ajax is not needed, these values can be hardcoded into the app using javascript.

Comment: hey thanks, and how can I store the selected colors, if the user clicks on submit?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the colors to your server and store it with PHP

Comment: Pastor Bones, are you doing freelancer work too? And how can I contact you?

Comment: sorry, pastor_bones@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple do with jQuery

here are some useful articles:
http://desizntech.info/demo/jQuery_color_animation/
http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/its-a-rainbow-color-changing-text-and-backgrounds/